# How to change the default partial in Symfony?

Tags: php, symfony1

I'm currently working with Symfony and I was wondering how to change the default partial.

In my components.class.php, I have my executeWhatever() that calls my _Whatever.php. But I would like to add a condition in my executeWhatever() so I can do something like this:

```
public function executeWhatever(sfWebRequest $request)
{
   if (myCondition)
      usePartial('_firstPartial.php');
   else
      usePartial('_secondPartial.php');
}
```

I could easily includePartial(); directly into my _Whatever.php but I have some Doctrine requests that I would like to make according to myCondition.

I've found that I could use includePartial() in my executeWhatever() except that it's still including my _Whatever.php by default.

So the question is simple: how can I do to change the default partial used by my component method executeWhatever() ?

Comment: Why not pass $myCondition to a components partial a then include partial there instead?

Comment: Cause as I said, the process is different (I mean database queries and other stuffs) according to this condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change the partial, but try these solutions: [Symfony: Is it possible to setTemplate for components?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1612727/symfony-is-it-possible-to-settemplate-for-components)

Comment: Thanks for the link ! So... Few questions:
1) "return sfView::NONE;" will remove the default partial right ?
2) What does he mean by "render the partial manually" witi the PartialHelper ?
3) I was also thinking about overriding sfComponnents class

What do you think about it ?

Comment: 1) `return sfView::NONE`will just render nothing; 2) `render the partial manually` means that you can load `PartialHelper` helper in component and use `get_partial()` function there; 3) I don't think it's necessary unless you'll use it wisely in your project